# How to enable auto start for my app in Xiaomi programmatically

Tags: android, service

I have a service in my app which needs to be running in the background all the time. On all devices, it's working fine except Xiaomi. I have read somewhere that we need to enable auto-start in settings for an app to keep a service running.

So please tell me how to enable auto-start programmatically, because the user will never do that.

Comment: you wont be able to do that from code until and unless there is some api from xiaomi that gives you access to that functionality. I am guessing auto start manager is an app( with privileges of that of a system app, since part of xiaomi modified os) , hence not possible. On the other-hand if the device is rooted you can actually disable autostart manager.

Comment: @Radix how  whatsapp , facebook and many more apps doing this?

Comment: I am assuming they have tie ups with Xiaomi to be in the whitelist. Buts its just a guess.

Comment: agree with @Radix on the guess part, which seems ugly, from xiaomi, for app development generally. Is there any update on the question? Also, i checked ["xiaomi devs ask us"](http://www.xiaomidev.com/ask-us.html) section, non responsive

Comment: @ShivamNagpal : Xiaomi whitelists the popular apps like Facebook, Whatsapp, Messenger by default. Others like us have to inform the user to enable it manually.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426313/how-to-fix-the-issue-that-the-activity-is-killed-automatically-after-some-minute/47426982#47426982, this answer is having almost all Intents for most companies phones.

Comment: check this link for all devices on earth https://stackoverflow.com/a/58913310/9699754

Comment: @venkat please provide any proof of Xiaomi whitelisting the popular apps, like you said

Comment: @JohnnyFive You can install any Facebook company apps like Facebook, WhatsApp or Instagram, then check the whitelisted apps. They will be in the enabled state in the Whitelist screen by default whereas your apps will be disabled by default.

Answer (score 29):

You cannot enable auto start directly, but you can redirect user to auto start setting screen and ask user to turn it on for your app. Use the below solution for xiaomi, oppo, vivo, letv, honor, asus, nokia, huawei phones. Autostart screen will be launched if it exists.

```
    try {
            val intent = Intent()
            val manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER
            when {
                "xiaomi".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true) -> {
                    intent.component = ComponentName(
                        "com.miui.securitycenter",
                        "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"
                    )
                }
                "oppo".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true) -> {
                    intent.component = ComponentName(
                        "com.coloros.safecenter",
                        "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"
                    )
                }
                "vivo".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true) -> {
                    intent.component = ComponentName(
                        "com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                        "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"
                    )
                }
                "letv".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true) -> {
                    intent.component = ComponentName(
                        "com.letv.android.letvsafe",
                        "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"
                    )
                }
                "honor".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true) -> {
                    intent.component = ComponentName(
                        "com.huawei.systemmanager",
                        "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"
                    )
                }
                "asus".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true) -> {
                    intent.component = ComponentName(
                        "com.asus.mobilemanager",
                        "com.asus.mobilemanager.powersaver.PowerSaverSettings"
                    )
                }
                "nokia".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true) -> {
                    intent.component = ComponentName(
                        "com.evenwell.powersaving.g3",
                        "com.evenwell.powersaving.g3.exception.PowerSaverExceptionActivity"
                    )
                }
                "huawei".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true) -> {
                    intent.component = ComponentName(
                        "com.huawei.systemmanager",
                        "com.huawei.systemmanager.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity"
                    )
                }
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            /*Timber.e(e)*/
        }
```

Quvonchbek Y answered

Comment: the activity name for vivo is incorrect. maybe they change it from version to version.

Answer (score 7):

Try this...it's working for me. It will open the screen to enable autostart. But if you try to disable from there it will close the app. I am figuring out a solution for that. Till then you can use this as solution.

```
String manufacturer = "xiaomi";
        if(manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
            //this will open auto start screen where user can enable permission for your app
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Mohit every time it is asking how do you filter that ask only once is there any callback method for this.

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran callback is not there since I am explicitly trying to call the activity.

Comment: how can i call i only once every time is asking the permission

Comment: you can also check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277671/clear-recent-apps-wipe-the-apps-memory-and-my-receiver-stopped-working/41360159#41360159

Comment: mine is still killing the floating window service any solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import java.util.List;

public class Utils {

public static void startPowerSaverIntent(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("ProtectedApps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean skipMessage = settings.getBoolean("skipProtectedAppCheck", false);
    if (!skipMessage) {
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        boolean foundCorrectIntent = false;
        for (Intent intent : Constants.POWERMANAGER_INTENTS) {
            if (isCallable(context, intent)) {
                foundCorrectIntent = true;
                final AppCompatCheckBox dontShowAgain = new AppCompatCheckBox(context);
                dontShowAgain.setText("Do not show again");
                dontShowAgain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        editor.putBoolean("skipProtectedAppCheck", isChecked);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                });

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle(Build.MANUFACTURER + " Protected Apps")
                        .setMessage(String.format("%s requires to be enabled in 'Protected Apps' to function properly.%n", context.getString(R.string.app_name)))
                        .setView(dontShowAgain)
                        .setPositiveButton("Go to settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                        .show();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!foundCorrectIntent) {
            editor.putBoolean("skipProtectedAppCheck", true);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isCallable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
}
}

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Constants {

public static List<Intent> POWERMANAGER_INTENTS = Arrays.asList(
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oppo.safe", "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.asus.mobilemanager", "com.asus.mobilemanager.entry.FunctionActivity")).setData(android.net.Uri.parse("mobilemanager://function/entry/AutoStart"))
);
}
```

[Reference Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it/35220476#_=_)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) 
{
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
                    } 
else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) 
{
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
                    } 
else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) 
{
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.MainGuideActivity."));
 }
```

Comment: i need to redirect to autostart manager screen in vivo ,"com.iqoo.secure.MainGuideActivity" it is stopping in halfway

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this library.
[Autostarter](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter). It is a autostarter library for different device manufacturers

Last time i used it, it had support for Xiaomi and Letv devices. I cant really give you code examples, but i hope it helps someone who stumbles upon this

Answer (score 2):

@rajkumar is right, but you have to take care with Xiaomi running pure Android, MI A1, MI A2 and MI A3 is coming, so you should add something like:

```
if (Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase().contains("xiaomi") 
&&
!Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().contains("mi a")){
 //intent
 }
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Muyangmin/e8ec1002c930d8df3df46b306d03315d

@javisilox This can detect whether device has MIUI, therefore can solve problem you described in a more general and precise way. (Tested on: MI A2 lite, Redmi 5 plus)

Comment: Is there even an autostart menu in pure Android like in Miui?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by following:

```
      if (manufactXiaomi.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
        if (!session.getVisibilityOfAutoStartDialog()) {Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);}}
```

if you want to keep running your service is the background you need to change some setting of your device [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804070/how-to-protect-background-service-alarms-to-be-kill-in-newly-launched-devices-in/45188694#45188694)

might above code works for you

Comment: how do solve by asking only once by using this it is asking every time

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran Programmatically we can't check the auto-start status. 1. Have one permanent setting for "Enable autostart" in ur App setting screen. 2.And show a dialog/card at your Home screen with dismiss option. And finally do this check only for the devices have this Auto-start problem.