# How to open MIUI system Activity programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

[image]

Is it possible to open the above page programmatically in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i know there is no implicit `Intent` to open this `Activity`.

To figure out how to do this explicitly, take a look at the Logcat output when opening this menu on your device to see what is going on. The flow should be handled by the `ActivityManager` at some point, so you can filter for it.

You should look for something like this in the log:

> I/ActivityManager: START u0
>   {cmp=com.miui.powerkeeper/.ui.PowerHideModeActivity} from uid 1000 on
>   display 0

After acquiring this information, you just have to create an appropriate `Intent` so you could start the same `Activity` yourself:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.miui.powerkeeper",
        "com.miui.powerkeeper.ui.PowerHideModeActivity");

    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    // this is not an MIUI device, or the component got moved/renamed
}
```

On a side note, you shouldn't open OS components in an explicit way like this. Whenever they change the class name or package of this component, your code will break.

Comment: what if I want to open an activity of oppo device?

Comment: @ShaifaliPundir The same as here basically. Open the `Activity` on the Oppo device and examine the Logcat output. From the log you should be able to figure out what component the system opens. Then create an explicit `Intent` for the same component (as shown above).

Answer (score 6):

MIUI 10.

For current app:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.miui.powerkeeper",
    "com.miui.powerkeeper.ui.HiddenAppsConfigActivity");
    intent.putExtra("package_name", getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("package_label", getText(R.string.app_name));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jump to app detail activity on XiaoMi Phone(MIUI)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.appmanager.ApplicationsDetailsActivity");
    intent.putExtra("package_name", packageName);
    intent.putExtra("package_label", "Dev Tools");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

This is used by Dev Tools App, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.trinea.android.developertools