# Clear all button kills all services running for app in Android

Tags: android, service, notifications

When user clicks on `Clear All` button in navigation, in few devices, OS kills all applications running in background. As a result, sometimes, user does not get Push Notifications.

Is there any way here to avoid notification service to be killed by OS?

This issue happens mostly with Android devices with `Customized OS`. For Stock OS, it is working fine.

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting user to autostart page of settings .Try referring more from this link.[auto start permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307864/11128798)