# Broadcast receiver not working when closed app

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

When the incoming call to the phone popup on the screen. The application is running when it is open. However, when I close the application completely, the phone does not show a popup even though there is a voice call. The broadcast receiver does not work after the application is closed.

My device is Xiaomi Mi8

This is my code:

```java
public class CallBarring extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private CustomDialog dialog;
    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    private PhoneStateListener listener;
    private Context context;
    private Button btnEndCall;
    private TextView incomingNumberName;
    private List<String> data;

    final NumberInfo numberInfo = new NumberInfo();
    Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
    NumberAPI numberAPI = retrofit.create(NumberAPI.class);
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
            return;

        else {
            this.context = context;
            if(dialog == null){
                dialog = new CustomDialog(context);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
                }else{
                    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                }
                dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
                dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
                dialog.show();
            }
            // Fetch the number of incoming call
            telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    String stateString = "N/A";
                    switch (state) {
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                            stateString = "Idle";
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            break;
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                            stateString = "Off Hook";
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            break;
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                            stateString = "Ringing";
                            dialog.show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

            telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                    System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
                    fetchUserInfo(incomingNumber);


                }
            },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        }
    }
```

Comment: add device details on which you are running this app.

Comment: did you find any solution i am facing the same issue when app get killed this receiver doest not work but android documentation mentioned that this will work even after the app will get killed

Answer (score 1):

Many android device has power manager and dose mode concept. so background functionalities get stop when app is in background.

You can use foreground service to register you BroadcastReceiver to listen PHONE_STATE.

Comment: You mean register a BroadcastReceiver **inside** of a foreground service?

Comment: Yes inside foreground service.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be registering your broadcast receiver in an Activity (I'm assuming). This means that your receiver only works when the Activity is alive. But when the activity dies, the receiver gets unregistered and so won't listen for anything.

You need to register the receiver in the Manifest instead. That way, even when your app is closed, your receiver receives `PHONE_STATE` events and can fire off your logic.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".CallBarring"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

docs: [manifest declared receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers)

Comment: I did that but still was not able to show notification for incoming calls when the app is closed.

Comment: finally it worked for me, it turns out for some phone models there's an `Auto-Start` permission that needs to be enabled manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383983/how-to-programmatically-enable-auto-start-and-floating-window-permissions