# How does whatsapp, messenger and other very famous messaging apps receive push notifications even when app is killed?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

one of the best ways to implement push notifications via android or iOS is with FCM. But its been several years now, that [this issue exists](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/368#issuecomment-539272893) about applications not being able to receive notifications when apps are killed by teh user. 
This issue appears only on android. And the FCM team says it is due to vendors. 
I've tried a lot of "potential" solutions I found online to resolve this issue, but none of them actually worked. 
I have read several stack overflow questions about this topic and now I'm kind of desperate.

So please if someone knows how to implement this functionality just as what we see on whatsapp, Messenger and all the like, please help.

Comment: Perhaps they run a service?

Answer (score 0):

Although some sources say that this is an issue of Firebase and more about the manufacturer who does not use Android's native ROM. Manufactures like One Plus, MI, Vivo, Oppo, etc use customised ROM (rewrite the behavior of stock Android). So when the app is killed, all its services are also killed. So to solve this you can change their settings.

For deep understanding you need to understand about autostart in different devices. Please go through below link,

[How to programmatically enable auto start and floating window permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383983/how-to-programmatically-enable-auto-start-and-floating-window-permissions)