# Foreground service with PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK going to sleep

Tags: android, background-service, wakelock

I try to create simple timer. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#cpu) I have permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` and use this code in the `ForegroundService`:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getString( R.string.app_name ) );
wl.acquire();
```

It is working well for most devices when screen goes off, but some devices, for example Honor 10i (Android 10), after 10-15 seconds go to sleep mode and timer based on `Handler` is sleeping.

I tried set off battery optimization etc., but this is not help.
What is wrong?

Note. If function in the `Handler` plays "tick" sound then it works fine.

Comment: "What is wrong?" -- perhaps nothing. Some device manufacturers are very aggressive with respect to power management.

Answer (score 2):

You should use REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission and ignore battery optimization for the app.

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

then call the below method in your app

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void ignoreBatteryOptimization() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (pm != null && !pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

You can also check this [link](https://androidboss.info/2021/10/23/android-application-ignore-battery-optimisation-programmatically/)

You can also check the below method for Honor 10i (Android 10). I've tested it on Xiaomi redmi phone. Hope it will also work on your listed of manufacturers.

```
public static List<Intent> POWER_MANAGER_INTENTS = Arrays.asList(
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oppo.safe", "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.asus.mobilemanager", "com.asus.mobilemanager.entry.FunctionActivity")).setData(android.net.Uri.parse("mobilemanager://function/entry/AutoStart")));

public static void startPowerSaverIntent(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("ProtectedApps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean skipMessage = settings.getBoolean("skipProtectedAppCheck", false);
    if (!skipMessage) {
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        boolean foundCorrectIntent = false;
        for (Intent intent : POWER_MANAGER_INTENTS) {
            if (isCallable(context, intent)) {
                foundCorrectIntent = true;
                final AppCompatCheckBox dontShowAgain = new AppCompatCheckBox(context);
                dontShowAgain.setText("Do not show again");
                dontShowAgain.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                    editor.putBoolean("skipProtectedAppCheck", isChecked);
                    editor.apply();
                });

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle(Build.MANUFACTURER + " Protected Apps")
                        .setMessage(String.format("%s requires to be enabled in 'Protected Apps' to function properly.%n", context.getString(R.string.app_name)))
                        .setView(dontShowAgain)
                        .setPositiveButton("Go to settings", (dialog, which) -> context.startActivity(intent))
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                        .show();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!foundCorrectIntent) {
            editor.putBoolean("skipProtectedAppCheck", true);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
}


private static boolean isCallable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Read the full article, [Click here](https://androidboss.info/2021/11/03/how-to-enable-auto-start-permission-programmatically-for-customized-android-devices/).

or for related answers, [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307864/5756788).

Comment: I am sorry but still stopping.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, did you do those two steps? One for ignoring power-saving and one for protected apps which is auto start.

Comment: You must use a foreground service for that. Do you use the foreground service?

Comment: yes it is, see my question

Comment: @Style-7
Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @Mohsin Falak No, I also called to Huawei support, but I need to call hihonor this is another China company.

Comment: Doesn't REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS causes issues on the PlayStore?

Comment: @Mohsin Falak I found solution now, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Honor 10.
Looks like Honor smartphones have non standard behavior.
So,

1. Ask user go to Settings-Battery and turn off "Power saving mode" (set on as default) or "Ultra power saving mode" to off.
2. Ask user go to Settings-Apps-Apps(two times)-Find your app-Battery usage details-Manage Manually and allow all.

After this very simple code start working.

Comment: Can't it whitelist the specific app rather than for all the apps?

Comment: @HasIEluS No. Battery mode is for all apps.