# Boot_Completed broadcast not receiving in app

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I am testing a very basic app for getting `Boot_Completed` broadcast on device reboot.  I am testing app on `android 10 OPPO device`
Following is my code

**Manifest.xml**

```
  <receiver android:name=".SampleBootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <!--For HTC devices-->
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**SampleBootReceiver.java**

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("MyApp", " Boot completed fired");
    Toast.makeText(context, "fired " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
        Log.e("MyApp", "matches intent");
    }
}
}
```

My application didn't receiving `Boot_Completed` broadcast on device reboot.

**NOTE** - If i start the app manually just after device reboot, then i am getting broadcast in my app and able to see logs in logcat. But when i didn't start app after device reboot, nothing print in logcat.

I even tried putting `showing toast` on receiving broadcast, nothing happens.

Please suggest !

Comment: Have you enabled auto start permission for your app from settings

Comment: @Nitish i have added only this permission in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Comment: You have to enable autostart for your app in device settings.

Comment: Please see how to [enable auto start from settings](https://www.techbone.net/oppo/user-manual/autostart) or you can you can do it [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383983/how-to-programmatically-enable-auto-start-and-floating-window-permissions)