# How to enable autostart for my app in Xiaomi devices

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, startup

My app successfully auto start in some devices like Sony Xperia, OnePlus 3, Lyf, Micromax. But doesn't in Xiaomi. Then I found on StackOverflow that I have to give auto-start permissions to my app in Xiaomi Built-in Startup manager. I have also done that but my app doesn't auto-start.  Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.missingcell.trackerapp"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <!-- for card.io card scanning -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyApCFp8fEsll0RO114zLWKQQ6EexTM488c" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.activities.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.activities.ChildDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.missingcell.trackerapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalProfileSharingActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.ProfileSharingConsentActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />


        <activity android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.activities.RegisterActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.activities.BuyPro"></activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.call.AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="9991000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="in.deepakpandey.AlarmReceiver"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.sms.SMSReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="9991000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />
                <action android:name="in.deepakpandey.SMSReceiver" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".gps.GpsTrackerBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.gps.GPSReciver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.utils.APIReciver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter android:priority="9991000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.utils.NotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.missingcell.trackerapp.utils.DemoDeviceAdmin"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- This is required this receiver to become device admin component. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.tuenti.smsradar.SmsRadarService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I have also checked these answers but cannot comment there due to my less reputation [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149198/how-to-enable-auto-start-for-my-app-in-xiaomi-programmatically
)

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't new on Xiaomi because Xiaomi has a feature called app permission, where a user has to allow the app to start automatically (Service). In your case the `Service` is not called, once its terminated from stack.

Go like this and allow your app to autostart:

`Settings > permissions > Autostart`

Code:

```
if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("xiaomi")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Use the above code to launch autostart activity.

Comment: I told that in my question that I have done that but still the app doesn't restart. See my question and comment below the question.

Comment: And If It is necessary to add this code still after giving permission to autostart then guide me where should I include this.

Comment: How would you check if the permission that they made up is granted or not?