# How to fix the issue that the activity is killed automatically after some minutes in newly version as like vivo and oppo

Tags: android

I made a app,This is the app that store the location information by interval and send it to the server
Services are working in background or forground mode.It is working well in common android phones.
Btw app is not working well in oppo and vivo
After launching the first activity,app(this activity) is killing after 3~5 min.

```
try {
Intent intent = new Intent();
String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
} else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
} else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
//intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity"));
            }
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 
PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            if  (list.size() > 0) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
               Crashlytics.logException(e);
            }
        Account account = createSyncAccount(this);
        Intent locationIntent = new Intent(this, UserLocationService.class);
        locationIntent.putExtra("extra.account", account);
        startService(locationIntent);
Intent i = new Intent(this, SynchronizeService.class);
SharedPreferences prefs = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
long synchTime = 
Long.parseLong(prefs.getString(Constants.SETTINGS_SYNCHRONIZE_INTERVAL, "210"));
i.setAction(SynchronizeService.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
if (!UserLocationService.isRepeated)
        i.putExtra(SynchronizeService.EXTRA_TIME, Long.valueOf("30"));
    else i.putExtra(SynchronizeService.EXTRA_TIME, synchTime);
    startService(i);
```

This is piece of my source.
Could you help me?I didn't find correct solution.If anyone have a solution?Could you let me know about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , this is because these devices only allow background services for some whitelist app by default. If your app also has to work like that means you have to enable **autoStart** from settings, below code will help you to make user to enable autostart for your app.If **autoStart** is enabled, your service will work well in background.

```
private void enableAutoStart() {
    if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("xiaomi")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow QuickAlert to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed when you are in distress")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",
              "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Letv")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow QuickAlert to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed when you are in distress")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe",
              "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Honor")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow QuickAlert to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed when you are in distress")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager",
              "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("oppo")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow QuickAlert to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed when you are in distress")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            try {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
              startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("com.oppo.safe",
                  "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
                  intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                    "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity");
                  startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception exx) {

                }
              }
            }
          }
        })
        .show();
    } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("vivo")) {
      new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).title("Enable AutoStart")
        .content(
          "Please allow QuickAlert to always run in the background.Our app runs in background to detect when you are in distress.")
        .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
        .positiveText("ALLOW")
        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
            try {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure",
                "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity"));
              startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                  "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                  Intent intent = new Intent();
                  intent.setClassName("com.iqoo.secure",
                    "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager");
                  startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception exx) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        })
        .show();
    }
  }

  public boolean checkServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(
      Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
      if ("com.sac.speechdemo.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: But dialog is showing everytime when start the activity
it should also not show if already enabled

Comment: Could you help it too?

Comment: Time being there is no way to detect weather autostart is enabled or not,so you can give a message showing this is mandatory and if you are not allowing,services will not work  and using sharedPreference you can set boolean check weather it is shown or not,I know this is not a proper answer and time being there is no other way.If the answer helped you means please give an upVote also.

Comment: By far this is the best answer but I'm facing another issue that is if I press Clear All button in recent apps then the service survives but when I manually swipe clear the app then service stops. So any idea to fix it?

Comment: can u post a new question with your service class.

Comment: @AshutoshSagar I have seen this on oneplus 5, android oreo

Comment: As Battery optimization is growing stronger day by day, only thing I can think of is WorkManger.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this through code. you can do manual settings for your application as mention below and your app will run your background service

**App Info > power saver > Allow Background running**

**You have yo select Allow Background running**

Allowing Auto Start won't work. It will stop background service after some time.

tested in Realme 1 CPH1859

All phones not have above setting