# FCM push notification is not getting in Honor phones

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem of getting push notification in honor,Gionee phones when the app is cleared from the background i.e. swiped out of the memory.I was using FCM technology. It is perfectly working(both, when the app is running in background and when the app is cleared from the memory) in other phones like Samsung, micro max, Lava etc .I don't know why the app doesn't allowing push notification in Honor phones.Code is giving below for your reference.

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

    // sending reg id to your server
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
    // sending gcm token to server
 //   Log.e("token" ,token);




}

private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("regId", token);

    editor.commit();
}
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService .java

```
   public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;


    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
       }
    }
}



private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

        Intent intent = new Intent( this , MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this , 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)

                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());

    }else{

    }
}



private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");



        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        Intent intent;

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        int uid = 0;
        Date dNow = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmmssMs");
        String datetime = ft.format(dNow);
        try {
            uid = Integer.parseInt(datetime);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            uid = 0;
        }
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
      PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(uid,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mNotificationBuilder
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
                    .setTicker(title)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel( true )
                    .setContentTitle(/*getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)*/title)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent/*resultIntent*/)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent))
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSound(notificationSoundURI);
        } else {
            mNotificationBuilder
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(/*getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)*/title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                    .setAutoCancel( true )
                    .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent/*resultIntent*/);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(uid, mNotificationBuilder.build());



    } catch (JSONException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}


private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}


private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}
```

}

Kindly suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this it may help ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426313/how-to-fix-the-issue-that-the-activity-is-killed-automatically-after-some-minute/47426982#47426982

Comment: It might possible that the payload you are getting with notification is inside only 'data'. if it is only inside 'data', data notifications won't be visible in background.

Comment: Since it's device specific, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39504805/4625829) might help give some reason.