# Managing Chinese devices with custom rom for background process android

Tags: android, service, push-notification

**My issue**

There are many chinese devices with custom Rom. They don;t allow apps `Auto Running` feature for background service

Reference : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793

**What I did**

I managed to open

1) `Auto Start` activity for chinese devices with custom rom (like XIOMI etc)

2) `Ignore battery optimization` screen for chinese devices with custom rom(HUAWEI)

3) `Ignore battery optimization` screen for chinese devices with stock rom(XIOMI  MI A1)

Reference : [How to fix the issue that the activity is killed automatically after some minutes in newly version as like vivo and oppo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426313/how-to-fix-the-issue-that-the-activity-is-killed-automatically-after-some-minute/47426982#47426982)

**My confusion**

How do I decide which are the all devices I should consider for managing this scenario & which screen to open (Auto start screen or battery screen)

Eg . XIOMI has custom rom for REDMI 5 , but stock rom for MI A1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way as of yet to accomplish this (reliably). You could of course query `Build.MODEL` and `Build.MANUFACTURER` for every single device and decide based on that, but that might not be feasible for everybody.