# bind service stops after 1 or 2 mins when phone is locked in some devices like oppo, one plus device

Tags: java, android, background-service, foreground-service

IN bound service when I lock the device after the 70- 80 seconds service stops I am testing on realme 3 pro and one plus 5 both having API 9 PIE. How to keep service running until the app is in recent activity. Even foreground services are also stopped. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: if you could mention your use case it would be helpful to suggest a solution.

Comment: Use [ForegroundService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground)

Comment: Foreground services also being killed. @SilverskyTechnology

Comment: Did you use [event type notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#foreground-service) with foreground service ?

Comment: Yes, there was notification indicating service running @SilverskyTechnology

Comment: What type of task you want to do in your service class?

Comment: what do you want to acheive  with service

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh ,SilverskyTechnology To keep phone reachable to server basically its app reachable to server. it's a VOIP app.

Answer (score 2):

Realme, Oneplus, Samsung, Xiaomi, Huawei and a few other manufacturers have their own layer of "Battery Saver" or "Security" that kills or restricts background running apps in order to improve security/battery backup, unless user white-lists your app in the relevant device settings.

What i found out about Xiaomi is that they white-list well known apps like Facebook, Whatsapp, etc. But you cannot request Xiaomi to white-list your app.

These manufacturer apps simply terminate your app process. So your app should behave in such a way that termination at any moment should not create inconsistent state.

Also, you can always show a popup to user after installation asking him/her to go and white-list your app in battery saver. In Xiaomi, the user will need to select 'Do not restrict background activity' and also enable 'Auto Start' for your app. As far as i know, there is no other solution.

[image]

[image]

Conclusion: Visit https://dontkillmyapp.com and see how the apps are whitelisted for your OEM. Once whitelisted, it will work as expected.
But out there in real world, it will get killed and users won't manually whitelist it.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Roms have it's own security apps and it close the app service when u remove it from recent or after few minutes.

To keep running your app in background you have to enable autoStart from settings

Refer this : [How to fix the issue that the activity is killed automatically after some minutes in newly version as like vivo and oppo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426313/how-to-fix-the-issue-that-the-activity-is-killed-automatically-after-some-minute)

Comment: still, service stops

Comment: In which phone ?

Comment: Realme 3 Pro  oppo device

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue from long time, Try to add `FCM` in your application and start service from it directly or else set alarm and startservice.
In some cases above solution work. i have added above solution in 4 project but succeed in only 1.

Issues which I have found while overcoming problem with firebase.

1. Firebase Notification coming to app but Background service not starting
2. Firebase Notification Not coming to application
3. Firebase Notification coming and service starting with Broadcast Receiver (Sometimes 
   service not starting directly from `onMessageReceived()` method of Firebase so i 
   decided to set broadcast Receiver ) but sometime its stop working.

Issue which I have found without implementing Firebase

1. If we set background service to run after every 5 mins than for 1-2 hours its 
   running on 5 mins interval but after 2 hours time gap increased and service runs on 
   15 mins of interval and in some devices its run on 20-30 mins of interval(i found 
   this in right time because phone may goes in ideal mode).
2. As mention in your question, sometimes any of above implementation doesn't work.

Tip :  What I found in system alarm log ?

1. I have set alarm for 2019-08-08 
   11:07:00 which not fired and current time is 2019-08-08 11:10:00 but its showing in 
   pending in system alarm log.

You can check system all Alarm set by your applications

```
D:\SDK\platform-tools>adb shell dumpsys alarm
```