# On Xiaomi or Oppo or Vivo phones - Application Task not working as expected

Tags: android, notifications, miui, oppo, xiaomi

I have a small android application project (Used for a local community news app)on android, which is (or was) working on API 22 and onward. Only a issue recently came to our notice is that on Chinese phones like Xiaomi or Oppo or Vivo our notifications (tried both local/Firebase) are not working even when the application is white-listed.

*I see some suggestions on online blogs to use AlarmManager (but I guess this is bad idea - for real time notifications), not sure*

I have also tried trading on code like below, but still no luck

> https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.4/Notifications/Foreground

What I've figured out is, if the app task is locked, it will be persisted and my app notification work.

See the image below:

[image]

How to programmatically achieve this?

Can it be a single code (or module) for all the versions of Xiaomi or Oppo or Vivo (or say MiUI)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i also faced this problem, i have tried many given solutions in oppo and vivo mobiles but problem still not solved.

did you try **onTaskRemoved()** method in Service class? when we swipe app or kill the app **onTaskremoved()** method is called instead of **onDestroy()** of Service class.

So maybe there is a solution if we send a broadcast receiver in this method which restart the Service.

And also look this thread also:

[How to enable auto start for my app in xiaomi programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149198/how-to-enable-auto-start-for-my-app-in-xiaomi-programmatically/44818978#44818978)

Maybe it helps.