# FCM message not received in several devices (Android) if the application in closed from navigation drawer

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

The `FCMService.java` handles all the background notification tasks perfectly if the app is running in foreground. When i close the application from the app drawer the aforementioned service stops handling the delivered fcm message, instead throws following log

> W/GCM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000
>   pkg=com.technobees.nalamdot (has extras) }

I've tested in following devices with user enabling `isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations` using the permission `ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`.

1. Oneplus 3t
2. Xiaomi Redmi 4, Note 4, Note 5 pro (MIUI optimization disabled)

Message sending from node server

`var message = {
        'data': notification,
        'token': token,
        "android": {
            "ttl": 0,
            "priority": "HIGH"
        },
        "webpush": {
            "headers": {
                "TTL": "3000"
            }
        }
    };`

in `FCMService.java`

`@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
       //passing the data to the NotificationUtils -> which takes action based on "event"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Inserting these lines in the android manifest worked for me,

`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to receive notification while app is in closed stated then try adding these permission in your manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: not working still

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: notification payload can be send using data tag or notification tag.using data tag
it will trigger the FirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived method. it will not work on some devices, when an app is in the background.
Refer this:---
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847835/android-fcm-not-receiving-notifications-when-app-is-removed-from-background/45810771#45810771

Comment: That log is mentioned above in question.

Comment: have checked the above link

Comment: The problem i found is that FCM messages is not handled in debug mode by these Custom Android Versions. But in production, its fine