# Not getting notification when app is closed in Lollipop or below version using FCM

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had implement push notification using FCM which work very well in case android version is grater than Lollipop when app is not running.

Any settings I missed out for Lollipop or below version.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: As i can understand you, this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016196/firebase-cloud-messaging-not-received-when-app-in-background  can help you.

Comment: try checking if the fcm token is getting generated

Comment: I got correct token and server side FCM response shows success in sending message also receive message in case app is in background or foreground.

Comment: may be your apps background service is not active.if you want to keep the application active for all time.just go to settings->app manager and activate your application.

Comment: I did not get meaning for activate app. My manifest have prevent phone from sleep permission.