# Android Development: Protected apps in a Huawei Smartphone

Tags: android, android-developer-api, huawei-mobile-services

I have an app who runs in the background, also if the user swipe the app from the recent app list.
Now can you in a Huawei phone protect apps. If there are protected, they are run in the background, starts if the handy is rebooted and so on. If the app is not protected it runs only, if the app is started and the screen is on.

- Is that a Huawei specific feature?
- Other phones with a similar feature?
- How can I detect this in my app? Api? Class?
- Can I protect my app as default? If I install it on the Huawei it is always
  unprotected.

Thanks for any hint.
Hans

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it

Comment: Thanks for your hint.

I knew this article before.
Is there any similar feature on smartphones of another company?

Thanks

Comment: Hey , did you find a solution ? Have the same problem now. 
Only difference is that now they renamed 'Protected Apps' to 'App Launch'

Answer (score 0):

from what Iv'e seen - Protected apps is a Huawaei feature. I haven't seen it on any other verdors' devices (I deal with devices from various vendors on a daily basis including Samsung, Google, LG, Huawei, HTC and others).

There is no way to tell of your app is on the protected apps list or not. not through API anyway. You may try to use reflection to do that but as always - with reflection you don't have a way to know if it will work in future versions of Huawei devices.

Iv'e mailed Huawei in regard to the app I'm developing in order to have them add my app to the protected apps list as it uses PUSH msgs a lot but they haven't gotten back to me yet. I'll update here if they do. I haven't found a way to add it to the protected apps by default.

good luck!

Comment: Any news? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: still nothing presumably... what a joke. Has anyone tried reflection?

Comment: If you do decide to go with reflection you should assume that the classes you are using (OS classes) may change in the future and your code may stop working. I only use reflection with my own classes.