# How to enable AutoStart option for my App in Xiaomi phone Security App programmatically in android

Tags: android, security, service, autostart

My App is working with good remarks in all mobile except MI. Because MI restricting my App background service to run. After enabling App in Autostart in Security, it working perfectly. So can I enable that AutoStart Option for my app in MI Security App through programmatically. Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

And My doubt is how whatsapp , facebook and many more apps default enabling Autostart Option in Security App in Xiaomi?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please refer attached link for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473230/android-how-to-enable-autostart-option-programmatically-in-xiaomi-devices/65827056#65827056

Answer (score 27):

Try this...it's working for me. It will open the screen to enable autostart.

```
String manufacturer = "xiaomi";
        if(manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
            //this will open auto start screen where user can enable permission for your app
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Its working fine, but App is crashing(Automatically closing) if I Enable -> Disabled app from AutoStart list.

Comment: Note that I found Redmi Note 3 (Android 5) has annoying bug which Autostart page requires user toggle off -> back -> toggle on to make it work after uninstall then reinstall the app (reinstall without uninstall no such issue). The second bug is if user toggle off the app, it will close the page and exit the app.

Comment: I detect miui with: `val isMIUI = (Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties")
                        .getMethod("get", String::class.java)
                        .invoke(null, "ro.miui.ui.version.code") as String? ?: "") != ""`

Because, a xiaomi device might not always be running miui, and miui might not always be running on a xiaomi, considering custom roms and unofficial ports, and their recent mi A1 with stock android.

Comment: Hi all but  how to check if autostart permission already enabled or not. Because if we use above code it will call every time

Comment: @PPD how to check autostart permission already enable or not ?

Comment: Is there a way to detect whether it is enable or not by user @Mohit Mathur ?

Comment: @AkashSingh, have you got a solution?

Comment: @KishanSolanki124, any solition for this

Comment: @Sony sorry, not yet.

Comment: there is no Android API to check if the the AutoStart is enabled or not. Though you can have you logic (may be you can use preference to set a Boolean for it) to check this. Please have a look here : stackoverflow.com/a/56335831/5685911

Answer (score 10):

Facebook, Whatsapp, Messenger and few more popular apps are whitelisted by Xiaomi. Hence they get enabled by default. Other apps need to be enabled by users. We don't have any other option.

We need to programmatically detect the manufacturer using     Build.MANUFACTURER in android and show a dialog which suggests the user to enable the app in AutoStart, if the manufacturer is Xiaomi

Comment: I am facing this issue for long days and also posted in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473230/android-how-to-enable-autostart-option-programmatically-in-xiaomi-devices.. Can you pls mention some reference links annotating  that Xiaomi allows popular apps ? I would like to share the same to our client

Comment: You can manually check that in any Redmi mobile. You can simply install any Facebook app, it will be whitelisted by default where other apps won't

Comment: Is there a way to check if the device allows the app to run on boot?

Comment: No. They don't provide any API to check that.

Comment: @RakeshL Have you found a solutions for how to check if it is enabled?

Comment: @Royz As Venkat commented, there is no Android API to check if the the AutoStart is enabled or not. Though you can have you logic (may be you can use preference to set a Boolean for it) to check this.

Comment: Please refere attached link for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473230/android-how-to-enable-autostart-option-programmatically-in-xiaomi-devices/65827056#65827056

Answer (score 0):

There is some other way. Install Aarogya setu app, app already has Auto-start permission. It seems, there is a way to whitelist apps for Autostart from online portal of manufacturer.