# Firebase notification is not getting on some devices?

Tags: android

I did Firebase notification in android but getting some issue in that when I close application then I didn’t got notification on some devices and these devices are:

1. Lenovo A6020a40 which is having os 5.1.1
2. Redmi 3s prime which is having os 6.0
3. Panasonic operating system is 6.0
   if anyone get solution for these devices please let me know.

Comment: are you sure that you are sending the device token which is not empty to server

Comment: yes i am sure about that because when i launch my application it work's fine but when i close my application i did't got notification on device

Comment: you mean to say you are getting notifications when your app is in foreground?

Comment: yes when my application is in foreground as well as in background it work's fine but when we kill the application then it is not working in these devices

Comment: okay then reformat your question with respect to your comment

Comment: did you extended the firebase notifiaction service class and firebase messaging service class

Comment: yes , i used this link for fcm demo please see for more info  https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 0):

For All Xiaomi devices, the only solutions seem to be:

> Enabling **Auto Start** on `Xiaomi` devices.

Apparently, WhatsApp and Facebook app are whitelisted i.e by default set to `Auto-Start:ON` by the device OS. That's why, no matter even if they are cleared from RAM, they keep receiving notifications.

[How to launch Auto Start Screen for Xiaomi devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41696993/5490548)

Comment: not working for me put this into my Mainactivity but still i am facing same issue

Comment: Was `AutoStartManagementActivity` launched?

Comment: No activity was not launched

Comment: just to be sure, did you try with Xiaomi device? And please share your code if possible. Would be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Also, you're recommended to set default values to customize the appearance of notifications. You can specify a custom default icon and a custom default color that are applied whenever equivalent values are not set in the notification payload.

Add these lines inside the application tag to set the custom default icon and custom color:

Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
     notification message.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

you may read more at this [FCM Recieve Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Comment: okay , are you getting notifications in other devices when your app is killed

Comment: yes, i am getting proper notification on another device

Comment: I asked you that are you getting notification in other devices when the app is killed or not?, also tell me how you are sending the notification using fcm console or from your server

Comment: well I tested the notification code in xiomi mi4i and found it working after the above code of my answer ,

Comment: hey, I found a link for xiomi devices http://www.androidcentral.com/how-fix-push-notifications-miui-8

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it for redmi 3s prime , for this device i provide auto-start permission manually , you can check it here "
https://xiaomininja.com/2015/08/10/miui-tip-enable-autostart-to-never-miss-a-notification-again/ "and solved. , if anyone found some solution for other devices please let me know .