# FCM not working for LETV device

Tags: android, push-notification, autostart

I am facing a problem in sending FCM push notifications to Letv devices. 
Letv devices are able to receive notifications only when auto launch option for my app is enabled and phone is rebooted. I can enable auto launch permission manually for my app by: Phone Manager-> Access Management -> Manage auto launch -> Enable auto launch for my app.

Please suggest if there is any way to enable auto launch permission programmatically in Letv devices?

Note: For Xiomi device, i am using code suggested by hardik: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40932178/5707364

Thank you.​