# Xiaomi BOOT_COMPLETED not received

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My aim is to receive BOOT_COMPLETE through a broadcast receiver. I have implemented it  according to Piyush's answer in [BOOT_COMPLETED not working Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441308/boot-completed-not-working-android) and it is working on a Nexus5. But it doesn't work on my Xiaomi mi5s even though I have turned on autostart for my app in MIUI's security app.

p.s: I am on MIUI 8.2.1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey little late but I just got to this issue also. Problem with Xiaomi devices is that they block autostarting of the application so it does not receive the **BOOT_COMPLETED** Broadcasts. To be able to receive it the user has to enable the application to autostart in settings.

There are already multiple solutions for this issue: [answer from Mohit Mathur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41696993/10169723) or [answer from Dika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43108234/10169723).

There are two main things to note:

- You cannot actually check if the app has the autostart enabled or not.
- This is not issue only for Xiaomi but for some Huawei, HTC and other devices too.

Answer (score 1):

To add to David's answer. You must also change the Battery Saver settings to **No Restrictions** on MI phones to receive the intent.