# Alarm manager is not triggering if app is killed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to create a scheduling application. I am using Alarm manager. It is working fine when app is alive. If I removed the app from recent applications Alarm is not triggering. Please let me any idea to resolve my issue. Herewith I attached my code.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(SettingsPage.this, AlarmManagerForSettings.class);
i.putExtra("requestCode", "100");
i.putExtra("AlarmTag",id);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SettingsPage.this, (int)id, i, 0);
am.cancel(pi); // cancel any existing alarms RTC_WAKEUP
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(SettingsPage.this, AlarmManagerForSettings.class);
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

**Broadcast Receiver:-**

```
public class AlarmManagerForSettings extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String requestCode = "";
        String alarmTag = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            requestCode = bundle.get("requestCode").toString();
            alarmTag = bundle.get("AlarmTag").toString();
        }
//Rest of code I wrote here
   }
}
```

**Manifest:-**

```
<receiver
  android:name=".AlarmManagerForSettings"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
  </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: did you checked some other mobiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the mobile Broadcast Receiver is not running..if Broadcast is not running follow below steps:
In Xiaomi devices, you just have to add your app to Autostart list, to do so, follow these simple steps given below:

> 1.Open Security app on your phone.
>
> 2.Tap on Permissions, it'll show you two options: Autostart and Permissions
>
> 3.Tap on Autostart, it'll show you list of apps with on or off toggle buttons.
>
> 4.Turn on toggle of your app, you're done!

[How to get MIUI Security app auto start permission programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995469/how-to-get-miui-security-app-auto-start-permission-programmatically)

Comment: Yes. Now it is working. Is there any way to enable programmatically?

Comment: I got the solution from here to enable the Auto Start. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995469/how-to-get-miui-security-app-auto-start-permission-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Write your alarm manager code in sticky server class and start this service as per yours functionality. Check after killing of app is updating.

Comment: Can you give more info?