# Intent for protected apps in huawei

Tags: android, android-intent, huawei-mobile-services

We know that Huawei and Xiaomi have '**protected apps option**' in settings options, this option kills our apps when screen is off, then can't arrive notifications and others... I wanna warn my users about this option and open this settings part, it's possible to open an itent in this settings directory? Actually I open settings with this intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it

Comment: If you can determine the class name of the settings screen, you can simply launch that `Activity`. It will be different for each manufacturer, and they can always change it in the future, so this isn't a very robust feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```