# Android - Huawei Protected apps

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, manifest, huawei-mobile-services

i'm creating an app on my Huawei P9 Lite. There are notifications, but when i close the app, notifications aren't fired. Problem is in "super function" Protected apps list. Is there any way, how to enable my app in this list from manifest permissions or code (Xamarin)? Some apps are enabled from default (Clash of clans...). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that there is no manifest permission for Huwaei as of now. But what you can do is to show a dialog box and tell the user to enable it manually.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35220476/6197251)