# Move apps into protected apps automatically when app install completed

Tags: android

Iam developing app with services when install my app in honor5x phone app not move authomatically into protected apps.when installing facebook app the app authomatically moved into protected apps.how can i solve this? any permisson needed in android manifest?

Comment: What are protected apps?

Comment: protected apps are battery saving feature

Comment: What's the purpose of the battery saving features if developers like you could automatically get whitelisted?? I would not be surprised that Facebook got whitelisted because they paid money.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. The user must manually add the app to the list of protected apps. Facebook is there because it is a "well known" app and they have probably paid Huawei to have it automatically added to the list of protected apps.

See ["Protected Apps" setting on Huawei phones, and how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it)