# Android Autostart bypass device manager app

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which needs to Autostart when the device is booted.

I've implemented the receiver and all i need. Now my app listens for the boot and everything works fine.

The only problem is that some **device manufacturer implements Managers App in their devices**.

For ex. "ASUS Mobile Manager" in Asus devices.

This managers help you keep your smartphone working good, they let you manage the resources and the permission.

The permissione management often include the **Automatically Start Permissions Settings**.

If i don't enable this permission **from there** for my app, Autostart doesn't works.

***How can app such Whatsapp have this setting enabled without the need for a user's intervention?***

Comment: I think Whatsapp uses Firebase Notifications and Android Service. That shouldn't be blocked by Manager Apps.

Comment: But you could also add this permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it), and this is the accepted answer's summary -

> There isn't a setting in the manifest, and Huawei has enabled Tinder
>   because it's a popular app. There isn't a way to know if apps are
>   protected.

So basically, WhatsApp is **enabled by default**, because Asus knows that it is a **popular app**, and think of it in this way - if Asus disabled AutoStart for WhatsApp on their Firmware, and after talking on forums and stuff, people with Asus phones get to know that it is Asus causing this issue with their Whatsapp, *why would they ever buy an Asus phone ever again* ?

Asus pre-installed Facebook and Instagram on their latest firmware, which is nothing but **bloatware** for many people.

You wouldn't face any such problem on Stock Android though, which is why stock Android is the way to go. :)