# REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS how to do it right

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have `IntentService` task in foreground mode, but in Android M+ the task stops in Doze mode. I read Google banned if the app uses intent to set themselves in whitelist. But if I use permission and check GRANT or DENIED, I get the granted result, but nothing happen. I don't see my app in whitelist. How can I add the app in whitelist without banned? (I added permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`)

```java
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
    int permissionCheck= ContextCompat
                    .checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);

    if(permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){

        //Should we show an explanation
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS)){
            //Show an explanation
            final String message = "";
             Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayoutView,message,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                     .setAction("GRANT", new View.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                         }
                     })
                     .show();

                }else{
                    //No explanation need,we can request the permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` is not a `dangerous` permission. You do not need, or want, any of that code. Quoting [the documentation for `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS):

> Permission an application must hold in order to use ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS. This is a normal permission: an app requesting it will always be granted the permission, without the user needing to approve or see it.

So, delete all that code.

> I don't see my app in whitelist.

That is because the user did not add you to the whitelist, apparently.

Requesting `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` grants you the authority, from a security standpoint, to start an activity with [an `ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS). Be sure to include your app's package as the `Uri`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, Uri.parse("package:"+getPackageName())));
```

The user will be taken to a screen where they can indicate that they are willing to suspend portions of Doze mode effects on your app.

> How can I add the app in whitelist without banned?

If you do not want to be banned, do not do any of this. Have something in your app that starts an activity with [an `ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS) `Intent`. This leads the user to the overall list of apps, where the user can toggle which ones are and are not on the whitelist. This does not require any permission.

The act of requesting `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` in the manifest is [what may get you banned](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/11/google-anti-trust-issues.html).

Comment: CommonsWare, thank you for detailed answer. It means I don't need the permission, only create intent? Am i right?

Comment: @Delphian: If you want to use `ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`, to lead the user straight to a page specific for your app and the whitelist, you need to request `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` in the manifest, but you do not need to use runtime permissions code for it. If you want to avoid the permission, use `ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS` instead.

Comment: this do not work in some vivo,oppo devices.

Answer (score 8):

Be aware of using Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS intent for the activity, this does not work on all phones and you will get a android.content.ActivityNotFoundException. In particular it does not work on Samsung phones running Android 6. The only combination that I have found works on these phones is to declare the REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS in the manifest, then launch an activity with intent Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS. I.e. the combination that is not liked by Google.

Comment: You've mentioned like adding `Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` to intent. is it like adding to `intent.setData` or some thing else?

Comment: @Arun - it's used in the setAction like so.... intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);

Comment: So what is final solution?
I am using oppo F1 (android 6) but even on adding permission it crashes

Comment: Use of `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` violates the Play Store Content Policy regarding acceptable use cases, as described in [http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html. ]

Comment: > Note: Google Play policies prohibit apps from requesting direct exemption from Power Management features in Android 6.0+ (Doze and App Standby) unless the core function of the app is adversely affected.

So I'm not sure it violates for apps that being affected by it...

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called BatteryPermissionHelper that might help you. You can check it out here: https://github.com/WaseemSabir/BatteryPermissionHelper.

This has implementations for different OEMs on how to guide the user to whitelist your app to ignore battery optimization.

It can be used like this:

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    implementation 'com.waseemsabir:betterypermissionhelper:1.0.0'    
}
```

```
private val batteryPermissionHelper = BatteryPermissionHelper.getInstance()

// check whether or not Battery Permission is Available for Device
val isBatteryPermissionAvailable = batteryPermissionHelper.isBatterySaverPermissionAvailable(context = context, onlyIfSupported = true)

// Show a dialog based on availability (Implementation left to Dev) and OnClick open permission manager
dialog.setOnClickListener {
    batteryPermissionHelper.getPermission(this, open = true, newTask = true)
}
```