# Android 9 background location tracking using foreground service

Tags: java, android, background, geolocation, foreground-service

I am using an android fused location client for background location tracking which will run even if the app is cleared from the memory. I am using foreground service for this. It is running perfectly for most of the devices except the Samsung Galaxy devices with power saver modes. I have also added the permission for ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS on app runtime but still, the Samsung devices do not track perfectly. I am also using geofencing intent service along with a partial wake lock. This app is working fine on all other devices. Please check the code that I am using for background locations. This is not the full code. 
Also when I enable location toasts then the distance is tracking perfectly even on Samsung. But when toasts are disabled then it only works for the first time in Samsung.

```
/**********LocationUpdatesService class********/
public class LocationUpdatesService extends Service {
      @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                onNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
            }
        };

        createLocationRequest();
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            getLastLocation();
        }

      powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
      wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "myapp::MyWakelockTag");  
      wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public void requestLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting location updates");
        //Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdatesService.class));
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                    mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            //Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
        }
    }

       public void removeLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Removing location updates");
        removeActivityUpdatesButtonHandler();
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
            wakeLock.release();
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            //Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not remove updates. " + unlikely);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service started");
        boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION,
                false);

        // We got here because the user decided to remove location updates from the notification.
        if (startedFromNotification) {
            //removeLocationUpdates();
            //stopSelf();
        }
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        // Tells the system to not try to recreate the service after it has been killed.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

I am using this Bound service in my main activity.
The above is just a sample code for anyone's reference. Please let me know if anyone knows the solution. I am just having trouble in the case of Samsung devices with a power saver. Otherwise, my service is working fine and tracking the distance perfectly.

Comment: I am also experiencing no location updates when the app is in Background, or screen is off. Do u experience this as well?

Comment: Please use google fused location updates and give users a warning popup if they have enabled their power saver. As in background location tracking the location will emit only few times each hour if a device has power saver or doze mode activated. So only way is to use  the google fused locations with a permanent notification that will display a message to user about purpose of the app to use the location.Background location will work perfectly in case of no power mode or optimized mode and will even work if screen is locked or off.

Comment: For Samsung devices with android 6.0 version , default dialog does not open due to samsung's bug, you have to directly open particular setting activity, cehck this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50840603/3497972

Comment: @meanstackdeveloper  Even after changing the battery mode to optimized in some Samsung models(S9+, S10, S10+ ), I'm only getting the location updates a few times in an hour. I tried both fused API and location manager, both didn't work. I am using a foreground service to fetch the location along with a partial wake lock. It is working perfectly in all other devices. But having issues with the devices I mentioned. Have you faced this issue?

Comment: With foreground service we need to display permanent notification to app users, then this foreground service will run continuosly in above devices. Also on android 10 we need to add this permission to manifest.xml "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />". I am using fused location api with foreground service along with it I am displaying a permanent notification to users.

Comment: @meanstackdeveloper did you manage to solve this? will you be able to share your code with me too i am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes background location tracking is working fine for me. In android 10 now we need to ask for another location <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />. Then users need to choose allow all the time if you want to track the location in background 24/7. Also one more thing from now on we need to show the prominent disclosure to users before asking for background location permission mentioned above. Otherwise google playstore will reject the app submission.

Comment: For code reference anyone can check this cordova plugin https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation. They have complete code with activity recognition + background location tracking with fused location api. In android 10 now we need to add permission for activity recognition too which works fine in android 9 even without adding this permission. Here is the physical acitivity permission android. permission. ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION.