# Android system is killing my app when it is background and waiting for onactivityresult

Tags: android

We developed an app which is running in android payment device(PAX). This device having low memory (1 GB).
In this app we are calling other app using ActivityResultLauncher and getting the result to store in our DB.

Out of 1000 cases 1 or 2 times our app is got killed while waiting for result and our app in background.

Here my doubts:
1)Is it possible to avoid that, my app got killed by Android
2)Is it possible to maintain the same state after app got killed, so when our app come to foreground we can capture the activity result..

We are using android:largeHeap="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to avoid that, my app got killed by Android

You can increase priority of your application, for example by starting foreground service, but anyway you should be ready that your app can be killed.

> Is it possible to maintain the same state after app got killed

Android provides all tools for it, you can read about them [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states).

Answer (score 0):

not sure how long are you waiting for result, but maybe some battery optimisation mechanism is killing your app in the meantime

check out [REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862176/request-ignore-battery-optimizations-how-to-do-it-right), maybe this "perm" prevent problem

Comment: We are waiting minimum 5 seconds to maximum 40 seconds. Some time app crashes within 5 seconds