# How to get string array with Protected Apps List (Huawei)

Tags: android, service, protected, huawei-mobile-services

I know how to launch the Activity where are listed the Protected Apps in Huawei, using this:

["Protected Apps" setting on Huawei phones, and how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it/35220476)

But I need to know if exist some way to get the protected apps list in a String and Verify if my app is protected.

Because my app have a wakelock, a service and even a JobService, and the Huawei still killing it.

But I think that removing it from Protected List is a good way to avoid this.

There is a some way to get the protected apps list, or avoid my app stilling be killed by the Huawei EMUI System.