# Service stopping after some time only on Huawei

Tags: android, service

I'm using Huawei P9 Lite - app is running in background.

WifiManager locked, Wake locked (PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)... and nothing - only on Huawei. Tested on many others phones - works fine.

Also used: ["Protected Apps" setting on Huawei phones, and how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it) - no change.

App is working for +/- 3-5 minutes after lock - then sleep for some time (5-20 minutes), then wake up for few seconds... Any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

It is the expected behavior if the doze mode is on:  https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: doze mode does not kick in after 3-5 mins. It takes about an hour