# How to programmatically identify Protected Apps in Huawei in handset android

Tags: android

In Huawei handset, there is something called Protected Apps. How to identify programmatically if an app is already in the protected app.

Comment: i found this link for similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it

Comment: I too followed that link, but there seems to be no process mentioned about identifying if an app is in protected apps section @AbuQauod