# Android set app in auto start FCM service on Asus or Huawei devices

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I develop an application that needs to send a notification with FCM.

But when I installed it on the Asus device when app closed (killed) data was not received in service.

I realized Asus and Huawei and some other vendors have auto start setting to save battery and user must allow to my app that have access background service.

**Is it possible to run this service without permission from the user?**

Some application does this! for example, Telegram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot whitelist your app in Auto Start / Auto Protect for ASUS and Huawei devices without user intervention.

The best course of action is to display a dialog in case the `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER` is `huawei` or `asus` and open up the Auto Start / Auto Protect page to make things easier for the user:

["Protected Apps" setting on Huawei phones, and how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it)

Comment: So how do some applications do this?

Comment: They don't. Popular applications are whitelisted by default on these devices, e.g. Facebook, WhatsApp, etc. For all other apps, manual whitelisting is necessary.