# “Protected Apps” setting on Android phones

Tags: java, android, android-intent, permissions, huawei-mobile-services

We can ask the user to protect our app, by using (e.g. Huawei phones):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there a way of knowing if the app got protected or not? I'm trying to avoid asking the user to protect the app e.g. every time the app is created.

For other intents, I can use:

```
List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                    new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()))
                    ,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

System.out.println("MY_intent_TEST_1(looks always true): "+( list.size() > 0 ) );

PowerManager pwm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

System.out.println("MY_intent_TEST_2(true when whitelisted): "+ pwm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(context.getPackageName()) );
```

P.S. I'm learning from: ["Protected Apps" setting on Huawei phones, and how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it/51726040#51726040)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because related interfaces are not exposed, currently you cannot get to know whether the app got protected or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shirley. What do you mean by "related interfaces"?

Comment: @user20191130 The interface to know if the app got protected or not. :)